Looking for a book with the story of a little boy who rode a train and was later found dead
I remember my mom reading this book full of many short stories and this one has stuck with me the most.
A boy and his friends decide to do this thing where they hop on a train and ride for awhile but they always get off somewhere. One day the boy and his friends are riding the train but I think they panicked for some reason? (I don’t remember) and everyone but him got off. I remember that the wind made him cold and I'm pretty sure he was in the city with the train still going fast. He never was able to get off and his parents/neighborhood start to search for him because he’s missing. It isn’t until some lady finds his skeleton somewhere. (Some of this might be wrong, this is a years old memory.)

Hi and welcome to Literature Stack Exchange. To make this work easier to identify, please add any information you have of the kind listed at the tag wiki for identification requests. This includes details about where and when you read it, what the publication date seemed to be, what the book looked like, etc. Please edit your question to add these details, don't provide them in the comments. Thanks!
